How trustworthy is ChatGPT 3.5, GPT‑4o and GPT‑4 with bible quotes?
When working with ChatGPT, I generally don't trust that the quotes that ChatGPT produces are accurate. However, I do note that they often are correct.
Here I would like to know how accurate ChatGPT 3.5, GPT‑4o, and GPT‑4 are with Bible quotes.
(I understand that this question might be off-topic here because it isn't a hermeneutical question in essence, but I still think it is a question important to hermeneutics, as it might highlight potential dangers or opportunities. Especially since a lot of people will be using ChatGPT as a source. I also wasn't sure if this question is postable on BH.SE directly instead of Meta)

Is this question better on BH.SE? Or is here the right place?

I doubt many people here could answer it because in general the community doesn't trust GenAI enough to know how unreliable it is for Bible quotes. I'd definitely never use it unless for the purpose of humour.

Generally you're right to be cautious of this - I've tried using ChatGPT 3.5 to produce all sorts of historic information - lists of early church texts, quotes from Josephus, and things like that. Every single time I've identified false or misleading information in it.
The newer versions seem to be getting better about referencing their information, so that's probably what I'd look for - can it give you a clear reference that you can check to ascertain the quality of the information? I suppose in that regard it's rather similar to using BH.SE - always check your sources!

I'm finding it's perfectly good for questions like "are there any other examples" or "please parse this word" or "why is this word a participle" or "where is this word used in the LXX" or "did Saint Paul ever express the view that x,y,z"
It doesn't know about textual variants and can't take account of them. And it doesn't understand poetry, unless someone in one of the books it has read has described a specific effect.
It speeds up research a ton but I wouldn't trust it with much more than the basic troll-work.
